# Compile Error in script

Tags: excel, vba

I have asked a question to search a file at 2 locations and opening it , Xbier answered to my question and given me the script but it is showing compile error i am not sure how to fix this,

```
Sub foo2()
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`enter code here`

Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\" 'path to folder
exists = fso.FolderExists(Path)

If (exists) Then
    program = "saplogon.exe" 'Program name to run
    shl.Run (Path & program) 'Run a program
Else
    Path = "C:\Program Files\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\"
    program = "saplogon.exe" 'Program name to run
    shl.Run (Path & program) 'Run a program

End If
    Set sapConn = CreateObject("SAP.Functions") 'Create ActiveX object
    sapConn.Connection.ApplicationServer = "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe"
    sapConn.Connection.Client = "100" ' only read access
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error?  Also, be aware you have backticks up top, `enter code here` in your code sample that may have been unintended.

Comment: put a single ' before 'enter code here' to comment the text out.

Comment: the error is - compile error , cant assign to read only property

Comment: still not working

Comment: *this* code does not produce a compile error on my pc. 

it produces a runtime error, which is clear since i have no SAP installed, but there is no compile error (after deleting the "enter code here")

Comment: IT highlights the Path= and gives the complile error as 'Cant assign to read only property' when i try to run this code

Comment: @DaDirnbocher Place the code into the `ThisWorkbook` module instead of (for instance) `Module1` and you will be able to replicate the error.

Answer (score 0):

Move the code out of the code module for `ThisWorkbook` and place it into a standard code module.

`ThisWorkbook.Path` is a read-only property and cannot be modified by code.

---

If, for some strange reason, you **need** the code to be part of the `ThisWorbook` code module, use a variable name that isn't a property of the `ThisWorkbook` object.

Comment: i want the code in Thisworkbook to make the user logon before starting other operations in excel

Comment: The code doesn't have to be in `ThisWorkbook` for it to be executable before starting other operations.  You could do that by simply having a `Workbook_Open` event in `ThisWorkbook` that called your `foo2` procedure - i.e. `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` `foo2` `End Sub`.  You should really only have code in `ThisWorkbook` that is relevant to the workbook object itself.